# How to concat many rows into one string using SQL within VBA / Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, concatenation

How to concat many rows into one strings? It needs to work with VBA / Access and SQL at execution.

Query:

```
SELECT name FROM mytable;
```

Result:

```
kim
lee
park
cho
```

I just want:

```
kim,lee,park,cho
```

Impossible?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? As your table grows, your string will get larger and larger, and eventually something will break.

Comment: Yeah, due to the nature of the tables it will never grow to long.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`-- sql`

```
 create table #user (name varchar(5))

    insert into #user (name) values ('kim')
    insert into #user (name) values ('lee')
    insert into #user (name) values ('park')
    insert into #user (name) values ('cho')

    declare @tmp varchar(50)
    SET @tmp = ''
    select @tmp = @tmp + name + ', ' from #user

-- select @tmp    


    select SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql query

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @STR=''
SELECT @STR=@STR+ ','+name FROM mytable
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@STR,2,LEN(@STR))
```

Comment: yes,so after concatenating , char make sure use mention select statement query SELECT  SUBSTRING(@STR,2,LEN(@STR)).which pick string form second locaion.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim rs as recordset
dim strSQL, output as string
output = "" 
'initializing to zero length string, pretty sure it does this by default but 
'just making sure
strSQL = "select name from myTable;"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql, dbOpenSnapshot)
'At this point you have the rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF = True
output = output & rs(0) & ","
rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

This should provide you with the output you are looking for.